# associative array mapping

Tags: php, arrays

Dunno if it is the right title or not, but i'm struggling to do the following thing:

say I have this array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id_ptp] => 1
            [denumire_ptp] => Hrană uscată
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id_ptp] => 2
            [denumire_ptp] => Hrană umedă
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id_ptp] => 3
            [denumire_ptp] => Hrană vie
        )

)
```

how can I make it to become like  this:

```
[
    '1' => 'Hrană uscată',
    '2' => 'Hrană umedă',
    '3' => 'Hrană vie',

]
```

Better question, is there a function that does that? Because I was not able to find it.

Comment: Look for array_column & array_combine.

Comment: [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951745/php-create-key-value-pairs-within-a-foreach)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create array from mysql query. Column2 as key Column 1 as value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11336095/create-array-from-mysql-query-column2-as-key-column-1-as-value)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`array_column` it is. Here is the one liner.

```
$result = array_column($your_array, 'denumire_ptp', 'id_ptp');
```

result : https://3v4l.org/qU0EU

Comment: I knew there'd be a better way than my foreach, nicely done